# Convert SQL Server query to be used in MS Access

Tags: sql, sql-server, ms-access

I have a working query in T-SQL but need to convert it (and use it) in MS Access. I get an error when I try to run this:

```
SELECT 
    tblKPIData.id, tblKPIData.KPI_id,
    tblKPI.KPI_Name,
    tblKPIData.ImportTimestamp, tblKPIData.Quantity,
    tblKPIData.FinancialMonth, tblKPIData.FinancialYear,
    tblKPIData.Zone_id, tblZone.ZoneName,
    tblKPIData.DMA_id, tblDMA.DMA_Name,
    tblKPIData.TargetOrResult
FROM 
    ((((tblKPIData
INNER JOIN 
    tblKPI ON tblKPI.Id = tblKPIData.KPI_id)
LEFT JOIN 
    tblDMA ON tblDMA.Id = tblKPIData.DMA_id)
LEFT JOIN 
    tblZone ON tblZone.ID = tblKPIData.Zone_id)
INNER JOIN 
    tblDashboardKPI ON tblDashboardKPI.KPI_Id = tblKPIData.KPI_id)
INNER JOIN
    (SELECT 
         a.kpi_id, a.financialMonth, a.financialYear,
         ISNULL(a.zone_id, 0) AS zone_id,
         ISNULL(a.dma_id, 0) AS dma_id,
         a.targetorresult,
         MAX(a.importtimestamp) AS importtimestamp
     FROM
         tblKPIData a
     GROUP BY 
         kpi_id, financialMonth, financialYear,
         zone_id, dma_id, targetorresult) AS max_kpi ON (tblKPIData.KPI_id = max_kpi.KPI_id
                                                     AND tblKPIData.ImportTimestamp = max_kpi.importtimestamp
                                                     AND tblKPIData.FinancialMonth = max_kpi.FinancialMonth
                                                     AND tblKPIData.FinancialYear = max_kpi.FinancialYear
                                                     AND ISNULL(tblKPIData.Zone_id, 0) = ISNULL(max_kpi.zone_id, 0)
                                                     AND ISNULL(tblKPIData.DMA_id, 0) = ISNULL(max_kpi.dma_id, 0)
                                                     AND tblKPIData.TargetOrResult = max_kpi.TargetOrResult)
WHERE 
    tblKPIData.FinancialMonth = 'Oct'
    AND tblKPIData.FinancialYear = 2017
    AND tblKPIData.KPI_id IN (SELECT kpi_id FROM tblDashboardKPI WHERE tblDashboardKPI.KPI_Id = tblKPIData.KPI_id)
    AND (tblKPIData.Zone_id = 5 OR tblKPIData.DMA_id IN (SELECT id FROM tblDMA WHERE Zoneid = 5))
    AND ((tblDashboardKPI.Status) = True)
    AND ((tblDashboardKPI.Dashboard_Id) = 6)
```

I get this error:

> Wrong number of arguments used with function in query expression 'tblKPIData.KPI_Id = max_kpi.KPI_id and tblKPIData.ImportTimestamp = max_kpi.importtimestamp and tblKPIData.FinancialMonth = max_kpi.FinancialMonth and ... etc

Can anyone tell me what is wrong? I really have no clue..

Comment: I think MS Access uses `NZ()` rather than `ISNULL()`.

Comment: See https://support.office.com/en-us/article/Queries-93fb69b7-cfc1-4f3e-ab56-b0a01523bb50#ID0EAABAAA=SQL_syntax

Answer (score 3):

`ISNULL(Field)` is valid Access SQL, but returns the same thing as `Field Is Null` (a boolean `True` if the field is `Null`, `False` if it isn't).

`ISNULL(Field, 0)` is invalid Access SQL, since `ISNULL` only takes one argument (hence the wrong number of arguments error).

Like Gordon Linoff said, you will want to use `Nz` if you want to replace `Null` with `0`.

Just find and replace all the `ISNULL` with `NZ`

Comment: If it works, please mark the answer as accepted. You can read [here](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5234/how-does-accepting-an-answer-work) how accepting an answer works, and what the advantages are.